# Create a maximised window that in non resizable?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have 2 windows now that i want to open maximized but should be  non realizable?how would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maximize the window use:

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

This will allow the window only to be minimized:

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
```

You can change it to the following if you want to disable minimizing as well:

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

Place the above in your form's constructor, it should look something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanMinimize;
        }
```

Or simply add the following properties to your window in XAML to make it look like this:

```
Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in WPF by following way:

```
  window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

In `XAML`:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    WindowState="Maximized">
...

</Window>
```

Comment: I was thinking of an XAML solution.Can it be done through XAML?

Comment: It could also be done in XAML in the Window-Tag, using the WindowState Attribute - which may be better practice.